# Updating Player Score

Tags: python

I created a Rock, Paper, Scissors game and I want the displayed player score to increase with every victory. A "for" loop is what I'm assuming is needed but I could be wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
import random
def play():
    choices = ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')
    user_choice = input(choices)
    computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
    is_win = (user_choice == 'Rock' and computer_choice == 'Scissors') or (user_choice == 'Paper' and computer_choice == 'Rock') or (user_choice == 'Scissors' and computer_choice == 'Paper')
    is_loss = (user_choice == 'Rock' and computer_choice == 'Paper') or (user_choice == 'Paper' and computer_choice == 'Scissors') or (user_choice == 'Scissors' and computer_choice == 'Rock')
    tie = (user_choice == 'Rock' and computer_choice == 'Rock') or (user_choice == 'Paper' and computer_choice == 'Paper') or (user_choice == 'Scissors' and computer_choice == 'Scissors') 
    print(f"You chose {user_choice}, Computer chose {computer_choice}")
    player_score = 0
    computer_score = 0
    def score():
        print("You", player_score, "Computer", computer_score) 
    if is_win:
        player_score += 1
        print("You won!")
        score()
        play()
    elif is_loss:
        computer_score += 1
        print("You lost! Better luck next time!")
        score()
        script()
    elif tie:
        player_score += 0; computer_score += 0
        print("That's a tie!")
        score()
        play()
def script():
    restart = input("Play again?")
    if restart == "Yes" or restart == "yes":
        play()
        script()
    elif restart == "No" or restart == "no":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        quit()
play()
```

Expected result: Displayed player score increasing with every victory.

Actual result (from Terminal):

```
('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')Scissors
You chose Scissors, Computer chose Paper
You won!
You 1 Computer 0
('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')Scissors
You chose Scissors, Computer chose Paper
You won!
You 1 Computer 0
('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')Scissors
You chose Scissors, Computer chose Paper
You won!
You 1 Computer 0
('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')
```

Comment: `player_score` and `computer_score` are local variables to the function to the `play` function. Not only are they only accessible to that function, they are specific to a particular *instantiation* of that function. So your recursive call `play()` creates a new instantatiation of the function with no knowledge of the previous scores.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's not really a question here. Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. That said, a for-loop is a good idea, and recursion is not (especially for someone new to coding, but also because of the recursion limit). I recommend rewriting this from the bottom up using a for-loop.

Comment: @slothrop Beside the point, but you *call* a function and *instantiate* an object.

Comment: Fair enough. What I'm groping for is this: the act of instantiating an object produces an instance. The act of calling a function produces a _ _ _ _ ? What's the best word to fill the gap?

Comment: @slothrop True. I would say "a call".

Comment: Right. That's the problem for me - "call" in my mind refers to the act of calling the function, it doesn't fit so well to the "bit of code in the process of running" that results from that act. But I don't have a better word really so...

Comment: @slothrop a cake!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the current code is that the `player_score` and `computer_score` variables are being reinitialized to zero every time the `play` function is called. This is why the score is not accumulating as expected.

You can fix this by moving the score variables outside of the `play` function, making them global variables. Here's a revised version of your code:

```py
import random

player_score = 0
computer_score = 0

def play():
    global player_score, computer_score
    choices = ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')
    user_choice = input(choices)
    computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
    is_win = (user_choice == 'Rock' and computer_choice == 'Scissors') or \
             (user_choice == 'Paper' and computer_choice == 'Rock') or \
             (user_choice == 'Scissors' and computer_choice == 'Paper')
    is_loss = (user_choice == 'Rock' and computer_choice == 'Paper') or \
              (user_choice == 'Paper' and computer_choice == 'Scissors') or \
              (user_choice == 'Scissors' and computer_choice == 'Rock')
    tie = user_choice == computer_choice

    print(f"You chose {user_choice}, Computer chose {computer_choice}")

    if is_win:
        player_score += 1
        print("You won!")
        score()
        play()
    elif is_loss:
        computer_score += 1
        print("You lost! Better luck next time!")
        score()
        script()
    elif tie:
        print("That's a tie!")
        score()
        play()

def score():
    print("You", player_score, "Computer", computer_score)

def script():
    restart = input("Play again?")
    if restart == "Yes" or restart == "yes":
        play()
    elif restart == "No" or restart == "no":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        quit()

play()
```

By declaring `player_score` and `computer_score` as global variables and using the `global` keyword inside the `play` function, you ensure that the values of these variables persist across multiple calls to the `play` function. This allows the scores to accumulate as you intended.

Comment: This'll work, but it's not great design or good practice. It'd be better to rewrite the code, like I wrote in a comment. (I didn't downvote though.)

Comment: Well, that's correct I agree, I add code that you expected)

Comment: While I agree that the use of `global` here is not ideal, it does seem to be the lightest change to the original code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

player_score = 0
computer_score = 0

def play():
    global player_score, computer_score
    choices = ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors')
    user_choice = input(f"Choose one of {choices}: ").capitalize()
    
    if user_choice not in choices:
        print("Invalid choice. Try again!")
        play()
        return

    computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
    
    outcomes = {
        (user_choice, computer_choice): "You won!",
        (computer_choice, user_choice): "You lost! Better luck next time!",
    }
    
    for outcome, message in outcomes.items():
        if outcome in ((choices[i], choices[(i+1)%3]) for i in range(3)):
            print(f"You chose {user_choice}, Computer chose {computer_choice}")
            print(message)
            if message == "You won!":
                player_score += 1
            else:
                computer_score += 1
            score()
            restart()
            return
    
    print(f"You chose {user_choice}, Computer chose {computer_choice}")
    print("That's a tie!")
    score()
    play()

def score():
    print(f"You: {player_score}, Computer: {computer_score}")

def restart():
    again = input("Play again? (Yes/No): ").lower()
    if again == "yes":
        play()
    elif again == "no":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        quit()
    else:
        print("Invalid response. Please enter 'Yes' or 'No'.")
        restart()

play()
```

Comment: why did you post two answers?